# How do I change the column widths on a PaginatedDataTable?

Tags: flutter

Right now there is so much space between the columns, even when I have a 4 character header and a 1 to 3 digit value for ranking, it's as if I could fit 4x that in each column.

I tried using smaller fonts, but the separation stays the same.

Here's what I am using to setup the PaginatedDataTable. I can't find any parameters across the Table/Row/Cell/etc that seem like the will affect width. The space seems automatic, yet wholly unnecessary. Thanks.

[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Tour Rankings')),
        body:
        new ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              new PaginatedDataTable(
                  header: const Text('Current Rankings'),
                  rowsPerPage: _rowsPerPage,
                  onRowsPerPageChanged: (int value) { setState(() { _rowsPerPage = value; }); },
                  sortColumnIndex: _sortColumnIndex,
                  sortAscending: _sortAscending,
                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    new DataColumn(
                        label: new Text('Rank', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 8.0)),
                        numeric: true,
                        onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player d) => d.rank, columnIndex, ascending)
                    ),
                    new DataColumn(
                        label: new Text('Prev', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 8.0)),
                        numeric: true,
                        onSort: (int columnIndex, bool ascending) => _sort<num>((Player d) => d.prevRank, columnIndex, ascending)
                    ),...
```

Comment: Not clear. Can you provide a screenshot + example ?

Comment: I ended up creating my own implementation of PaginatedDataTable and DataTable so I could adjust the fixed padding values embedded in Data Table and make some other tweaks.

Comment: Could you share how did you solve it?

Answer (score 5):

There is a property of paginated data table in flutter as columnSpacing.
This value defaults to 56.0 as per Material Design specifications.

You can change the value as per your requirement to change the horizontal margin between the contents of columns.

```
              PaginatedDataTable(
                showCheckboxColumn: false,
                columnSpacing: 10.0,
                header: Center(
                  child: Text("Statement"),
                ),
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Date")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Particular")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Debit")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Credit")),
                  DataColumn(label: Text("Detail")),
                ],
                source: YourDataSource(),
              ),
```

It should look something like this:
[image: Changed column Width Image]

Comment: I don't quite grasp the definition in [the docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable/columnSpacing.html)---does this act as a pseudo `min-width` property? Can we just set `columnSpacing: 1.0`, then add box-like widgets to each `DataColumn > label`, and set each DataColumn width individually (e.g. `label: SizedBox(width: 24)`, `BoxConstraints`, or `Container`)? Although it seems to work, is this reliable across devices/platforms? Side effects?

Answer (score 0):

After [this diff](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/33628) you can set `horizontalMargin` and `columnSpacing` to achieve custom column widths.

```
  /// The horizontal margin between the edges of the table and the content
  /// in the first and last cells of each row.
  ///
  /// When a checkbox is displayed, it is also the margin between the checkbox
  /// the content in the first data column.
  ///
  /// This value defaults to 24.0 to adhere to the Material Design specifications.
  final double horizontalMargin;

  /// The horizontal margin between the contents of each data column.
  ///
  /// This value defaults to 56.0 to adhere to the Material Design specifications.
  final double columnSpacing;
```

Answer (score -1):

I've also encountered the same problem with the flexibility of flutter PaginatedDataTable layout. 
My solution was to extend the constructor of the DataTable with the layout variables:

```
FlexibleDataTable({
    Key key,
    @required this.columns,
    this.sortColumnIndex,
    this.sortAscending = true,
    this.onSelectAll,
    this.headingRowHeight = 56.0,
    this.dataRowHeight = 48.0,
    this.tablePadding = 24.0,
    this.columnSpacing = 56.0,
    this.sortArrowPadding = 2.0,
    this.headingFontSize = 12.0,
    @required this.rows,
  }
```

Of course I had to implement FlexiblePaginatedDatatable to use the FlexibleDataTable:

```
new SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: new FlexibleDataTable(
        key: _tableKey,
        columns: widget.columns,
        sortColumnIndex: widget.sortColumnIndex,
        sortAscending: widget.sortAscending,
        onSelectAll: widget.onSelectAll,
        columnSpacing: 20.0,
        dataRowHeight: 40.0,
        rows: _getRows(_firstRowIndex, widget.rowsPerPage)
    )
),
```

The Flutter team should include this features in the official version of DataTable and PaginatedDataTable so others don't need to implement ad hoc versions for such trivial stuff. The issue exists and we'll see when it will be done.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12775

Comment: can you provide the `FlexibleDataTable` class?

Comment: Up you have the constructor and the variables aren't constant any more but get their values from the constructor:

final double headingRowHeight;
  final double dataRowHeight;
  final double tablePadding;
  final double columnSpacing;
  final double sortArrowPadding;
  final double headingFontSize;



I'm sorry but I can't paste all the class because it's too long for a comment.
I think I didn't change any other thing from the flutter DataTable class.